# Programmatically duplicating ConstraintLayouts and its contents for unknown amounts of repeated use

Tags: java, android, android-constraintlayout

I have a layout .xml file containing a ConstraintLayout that I want to repeatedly use for a carpool app I'm building.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/reservationsTemplate"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingHorizontal="10dp"
    android:paddingVertical="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rides_border">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/carModel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/spotify_font_bold"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:text="Car name"
        android:textColor="@color/mainColour"
        android:textSize="20sp"

        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/typeOfVehicle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/spotify_font"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:text="Vehicle Type"
        android:textColor="@color/mainColour"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:paddingEnd="5dp"

        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/carModel"
        app:drawableTint="@color/mainColour"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ownedBy"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/spotify_font"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:text="Owned by xxx"
        android:textColor="@color/mainColour"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:paddingEnd="5dp"

        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/typeOfVehicle"
        app:drawableTint="@color/mainColour"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/distanceFromUser"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/spotify_font"
        android:drawablePadding="2dp"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:text="0.5km"
        android:textColor="@color/mainColour"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:paddingEnd="2dp"

        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/ownedBy"
        app:drawableStartCompat="@drawable/location_smaller"
        app:drawableEndCompat="@drawable/dot_smaller"
        app:drawableTint="@color/mainColour"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/basePrice"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/spotify_font"
        android:drawablePadding="2dp"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:text="9.00"
        android:textColor="@color/mainColour"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:paddingEnd="2dp"


        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/distanceFromUser"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/ownedBy"
        app:drawableStartCompat="@drawable/dollar_smaller"
        app:drawableEndCompat="@drawable/dot_smaller"
        app:drawableTint="@color/mainColour" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/capacity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/spotify_font"
        android:drawablePadding="2dp"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:text="5 pax"
        android:textColor="@color/mainColour"
        android:textSize="15sp"


        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/basePrice"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/ownedBy"
        app:drawableStartCompat="@drawable/car_seat_smaller"
        app:drawableTint="@color/mainColour" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="85dp"
        android:src="@drawable/border"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

that looks like this:[image]

My goal is to duplicate this ConstraintLayout for how many cars there are and to stack them vertically on top of each other. However, when I tried to test it out, it gave a "java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first."

CarpoolFragment.java

```java
package com.example.ciscarpool.fragments;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import com.example.ciscarpool.R;

public class CarpoolFragment extends Fragment {
    private LinearLayout ridesView;

    public CarpoolFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_carpool, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        if (getActivity() != null && isAdded()) {
            elementsSetUp();

            ConstraintLayout cl = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.reservationsTemplate);

            ridesView.addView(cl, 0);
            ridesView.addView(cl, 0);

        }
    }

    private void elementsSetUp() {
        ridesView = (LinearLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.ridesView);
    }
}
```

fragment_carpool.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:background="@color/white"
    tools:context=".fragments.CarpoolFragment">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingHorizontal="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/spotify_font_bold"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/mainColour"
            android:textSize="32sp"
            android:text="Carpool Reservation"

            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/info"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/spotify_font"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:textColor="@color/mainColour"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:text="Reserved rides will show up under Your Reservations. It is your responsibility to be at the owner's location every morning. Feel free to reach out to the owner using the listed contact information."

            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/title" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="15dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ridesView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include layout="@layout/reservation_list"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Logcat

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.ciscarpool, PID: 12772
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:5323)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:5146)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:5083)
    at com.example.ciscarpool.fragments.CarpoolFragment.onViewCreated(CarpoolFragment.java:43)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:3147)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:588)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:272)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1943)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1839)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1782)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$5.run(FragmentManager.java:565)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:236)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8057)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:620)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1011)
```

I'm just extremely confused because if I follow some answers online and removeView() on the child's parent

```java
((ViewGroup) cl.getParent()).removeView(cl);
```

It's counter productive to what I want because I'm back to just one ConstraintLayout in the LinearLayout.

Comment: do you want to create a vertical list like structure?

Comment: It looks like you want to use a RecyclerView.  There are many examples of ConstraintLayout being used in RecyclerView

Comment: You are looking up a _ConstraintLayout_ that already exists in the layout and trying to add it two more times with `ridesView.addView(cl, 0)`. The _ConstraintLayout_ you lookup already has a parent and a child view can only have one parent. You will need to create a new _ConstraintLayout_ for each `addview()`.